# Convert GIF into video - xCode 8 and swift 3

Tags: converters, swift3, gif, xcode8

Does anyone know a good library for swift that can convert GIF or array of images into a video? Currently I'm using this library HJImagesToVideo to do the job, but it's taking very long time to convert a very short GIF animation

Comment: FFMPEG  will allow you to create a video, https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding-example_8c-source.html

Comment: have u used this to successfully convert GIF to video?

Comment: No, but assuming you can extract the frames from the GIF, it's the standard code for building MPEG videos.

Comment: I can extract frame from GIF already, I just need a library that can convert those frames into movie quickly